# How create automatically Db (identity) when I delete it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-identity

I want create automatically the db when it's deleted. Because I want to make sure that my site works even when the db has been removed (school project). Currently when I delete my DB. The program creates the DB but without the tables. So when I add an offer with my form I have an error because the offer table does not exist in the DB.

This is my identityModel :

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("OfferProject", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new Bd());
    }


    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }

    public DbSet<Offer> Offers { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? If so you can use DbContext.EnsureCreated().

Comment: Sorry my english is bad what is EF ? I use code first (identity,mvc).

Comment: Ah ok it's entity framework. Yes, I use it. Where I put this ?

Comment: You should have EnsureCreated() method then. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Infrastructure_DatabaseFacade_EnsureCreated.

Comment: @Dimitar It's not very good because  I use migration

Comment: Even the user table not created.